# Оплата, уплата, платеж, платежка - в чем разница?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова

Какая разница между словами: "оплата", "уплата", "платеж" и "платежка"?

Спасибо!

Comment: "Уверена" пишется с одним "н" (хотя уверенность - с двумя). Слово "титл" - компьютерный сленг, которого многие не знают (я, например). Более правильный порядок слов: "я не уверена, что писать надо здесь, в заголовке".

Comment: Спасибо, я поняла, что тако титл, только нее поняла, что надо писать в титле/заголовке (спасибо за слово), а что внизу...То есть, где поставить вопрос...

Comment: "В титле" нужно писать сам вопрос, достаточно коротко. Внизу нужно описать свои мысли по поводу этого вопроса - с какой трудностью вы столкнулись, что находили по этой теме, но не смогли разобраться, в чем собственно состоит эта трудность, почему вы думаете что слова похожи или непохожи и т. п.

Answer (score 4):

**оплата** - употребляется с указанием того, за что платятся деньги (оплата товара, оплата проезда), и - в отличие от слова "**плата**" - всегда без предлога (типичная ошибка: *"оплата за проезд"* вместо выражений *"плата за проезд"* или *"оплата проезда"*)

**уплата** (форм.) - употребляется без предлога и с упоминанием денежной формы (уплата суммы денег за что-то, пошлины, штрафа, взносов)

**платёж** - действие по перечислению денег за услуги (осуществить, произвести платёж)

**платёжка** (неформ.) - документ, подтверждающий факт и размер оплаты чего-либо

Comment: А плата вообще, это что тогда, н совсем то что и оплата? Спасибо!

Comment: Плата - денежные средства в размере, требуемом за товар или услугу; денежная компенсация. Например, заработная плата (сумма денег за оговоренный период работы или какой-либо её результат), плата за электричество, плата за проезд и т.п. Плату за товар можно передать продавцу (кассиру) или перечислить; такое действие будет "оплатой товара".

Answer (score 3):

"**Платёжка**" - это разговорное сокращение для "*платёжное поручение*" (или "*платёжный документ*"), то есть "*платёжка*" - это **документ** (*order*).

**Оплата**, **уплата**, **платёж** обозначают *действия* по соответствующим глаголам (*оплатить*, *уплатить*, *платить*). Поскольку данные глаголы синонимичны (разница только в видах: совершенный-несовершенный), то и существительные, в целом, почти взаимозаменяемы.

**Уплата** - редко встречается в современной "обычной" речи, в основном в формальных выражениях, типа "*уплата налогов*".

**Оплата** - более нейтральное слово.

**Платёж** может обозначать как само действие (*payment*), так и сумму платежа (*total*).

Comment: Платежка is only пратежное поручение, never any other thing.

Comment: @Anixx "Платежное поручение" - это "нормальный" банковский документ (форма 040160); "платежкой" его называют бухгалтеры и иже с ними. А та "платежка", по которой граждане оплачивают коммуналку - это как раз "платежный документ" (например, форма ПД-4).

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, платежка это и  месячные счеты (за воду, газ...)?

Comment: @SonjaKalaba Да, именно так (только правильно будет не "счёты", а "счета").